# How can I get the content by the User Id when using GroupBy in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
//Used to get the data I wanted
var MatchResult = (from a in User
             join b in UserResult on a.Id equals b.UserId
             where a.Status == "Active" select new
             {
                  a.Id,b.Win,b.Lost,b.WinRate
             }
//Used to Append the info grouped By UserId
var result =  MatchResult.GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
              .Select(grp => new { UserId= grp.Key, 
              UserEmail = grp.Select(x => x.UserEmail ).FirstOrDefault(),
              Content = MatchResult.Where(x => x.UserId== grp.Key).ToList() }).ToList();
```

As the picture shown below, Columns for content is getting a repetitive from userId 1 I try to use read the linq `var result` in order to sort out the content by Where clause. but turns out I am getting this error message

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

[image]

Comment: Add `MatchResult.GroupBy(x => x.UserId).AsEnumerable()` You need all records in any case.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv no, I just need the content to display the match result data according to the user ID